# Limit number of total records that a JdbcPagingItemReader can read in a Spring Batch project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am trying to read a database table that has millions of records and I am using JdbcPagingItemReader for that reason.

However, I am at the testing phase for now and I am trying to limit number of total records that I can read using `JdbcPagingItemReader`.
I know this should be simple, its just hiding somewhere.

This is how my reader looks like:

```
   @Bean (name = "metadataItemReader")
   public ItemReader<DocumentMetadata> itemReader( @Value( "${count}" ) int count ) {

      JdbcPagingItemReader<DocumentMetadata> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
      final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
      sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
      sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select id, file_path, file_name, extension, created_by, TO_CHAR(create_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as create_date");
      sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from document_metadata");
      //sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.l
      sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey("id");
      try {
         reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
      } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error(e.getMessage());
      }
      reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
      reader.setPageSize(10);
      reader.setRowMapper( new MetadataRowMapper() );
      return reader;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JdbcPagingItemReader` is a `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` bean, it has a `maxItemCount` property which you can set in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you! that was what I needed.